# bs4 p tags returning as None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import bs4
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://www.the961.com/latest-news/lebanon-news/').text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):

    title = article.h3.text
    print(title)

    date = article.find('span', class_='byline-part date')
    if date: print('Date:', date.text)

    author = article.find('span', class_="byline-part author")
    if author: print('Author:', author.text)

    link = article.find('h3', class_='title').a['href']
    link_r = requests.get(link).text
    
    soup_link = bs4.BeautifulSoup(link_r, 'lxml')
```

// scraping link from title, then opening that link and trying to scrape the whole article, very new to this so I don't know what to do!

```
    for article in soup_link.find_all('article'):
        paragraph = article.find('p')
        print(paragraph)


    print()
```

Comment: What <p> tags are you trying to scrape? the entire article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some pages the `<p>` tags are not under an `<article>`, and therefor is returning `None`. Instead, to scrape all the paragraphs (and `<li>` tags if they exist) use the following CSS Selector: `.entry-content > p, .entry-content li`.

To use a CSS Selector, use the [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find_all()`.

---

In your code example:

```
import bs4
import requests


r = requests.get("https://www.the961.com/latest-news/lebanon-news/").text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

for article in soup.find_all("article"):
    title = article.h3.text
    print(title)

    date = article.find("span", class_="byline-part date")
    if date:
        print("Date:", date.text)

    author = article.find("span", class_="byline-part author")
    if author:
        print("Author:", author.text, "\n")

    link = article.find("h3", class_="title").a["href"]
    link_r = requests.get(link).text
    soup_link = bs4.BeautifulSoup(link_r, "lxml")
    
    # Select all `p` tags (and `li`) under the class `entry-content`
    for page in soup_link.select(".entry-content > p, .entry-content li"):
        print(page.get_text(strip=True))
    print("-" * 80)
    print()
```